# How to change CSS style for scrollbar in react virtualized MultiGrid?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-virtualized, react-grid-layout

I am using react virtualized MultiGrid to display the data.

https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/MultiGrid.md

I want to change the CSS style for Scrollbar used in the MultiGrid. 
For example, I want to apply something like:

```
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: XXX;
  }
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: XXX;
  }
```

How I can apply the above styles for Scrollbar in react virtualized MultiGrid?

I tried passing the ***style*** but it didn't work. An example will be very much helpful.

Comment: Try applying the css using the parent/child or descendant operator

Answer (score 0):

You can apply styles to scrollbar this way:

```css
&.your-element::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 15px;
}

&.your-element::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.colors.menuBorder};
  border-radius: ${props => props.theme.borderRadius.whitePanel};
}
```

But keep in mind that it is not an advised practice to alter the default system scrollbar styles (as they vary between different operating systems and browsers) and can have unwanted effects.